# Why is my repeater control empty on postback?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I think this is a "doh" moment caused by me not having dome WebForms dev for a few years..

I have a repeater which which contains a bunch of checkboxes:

```
<asp:Repeater EnableViewState="true" ID="IDTypesRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="IdTypesRepeaterItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate/>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox EnableViewState="true" ID="chkIdType" Text="<%# ((KeyValuePair<string,int>)Container.DataItem).Key %>" runat="server" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="idType" Value="<%# ((KeyValuePair<string,int>)Container.DataItem).Value %>" runat="server"/>
                            <br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

I need to get the checkboxes that are selected in the code behind:

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in IDTypesRepeater.Items)
        {
            if ( ((CheckBox)repeaterItem.FindControl("chkIdType")).Checked )
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
```

But on postback, this code isn't working! I know about always databinding a repeater, so I've done this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDTypesRepeater.DataSource = DocTemplateHelper.GetApplicableIDTypes().Where(type => type.Value != 0);
    IDTypesRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

So this repopulates the repeater, but the Update code never finds any checked checkboxes.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind in the Page_Init event

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDTypesRepeater.DataSource = DocTemplateHelper.GetApplicableIDTypes().Where(type => type.Value != 0);
    IDTypesRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Yup - that's done the job.. Almost. I also had a cheeky "Page.DataBind" elsewhere in my page load that I needed to remove that was causing problems, so getting rid of that too seems to have sorted it all :)

Comment: I have never ever ever had a good experience with Page.DataBind. Gave it up for lent years ago :)

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to use the `!Page.IsPostBack` method in your pageload.
Otherwise, the Repeater will keep getting reset, and all your checkboxes
will be in there default value (unchecked)

Comment: If I wrap that code in a IsPostBack check, then the repeater is always empty on postback. As explained here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325980/why-is-the-asp-net-repeater-items-collection-empty-when-controls-are-on-the-scr)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. You are binding the control on postback hence losing the values. You can bind it after handling any event to show the updated record.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
      IDTypesRepeater.DataSource = DocTemplateHelper.GetApplicableIDTypes().Where(type => type.Value != 0);
      IDTypesRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: As per previous answer, this makes my repeater "empty", since repeaters need to be bound on every post (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: @MattRoberts, is viewstate enabled for your control/page? I won't suggest doing it in `Page_Init`. The issue might be because that your control is getting bound somewhere else in the code as well that's cuasing this issue